# Why the frequency response plots (of causal filters) only show positive frequency?

Tags: filters, frequency-response, causality

Take an example of the below plot for an LPF (Source : [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response#Estimation_and_plotting))

[image]

The plot starts from $0$. We know that the fourier transform of any signal brings in negative frequencies due to complex exponentials (which are just as **real** as positive frequencies, just to be clear) but most of the frequency response plots I have observed for **practical** **causal** filters, they start from $0$.

Indeed, the frequency response of an ideal LPF is a [rectangular function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) symmetric about the $jw$ axis and the impulse response is a **non-causal** [sinc function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter).

I have the following questions: Why do we represent/plot the frequency response of a **causal** filter with only positive frequency plane? Does it have to do something with making the *non-causal ideal sinc filter*, a causal one? (But don't we have to make the impulse response [time domain] causal in order to achieve that? [although I don't know what's the frequency response of a *causal sinc*]) or is it *understood* that there is a symmetric negative frequency  part and we just ignore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with causality. The frequency response of a real-valued filter (i.e., one with a real-valued impulse response) is (conjugate) symmetric, i.e., the negative frequencies are redundant. That's why it is sufficient to show the frequency response at non-negative frequencies only.

You can easily see that symmetry as follows. The frequency response of a system with impulse response $h(t)$ is given by

$$H(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\tag{1}$$

If $h(t)$ is real-valued, taking the complex conjugate of $(1)$ gives

$$H^*(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h^*(t)e^{j\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{j\omega t}dt=H(-\omega)\tag{2}$$

So, for real-valued $h(t)$, we have

$$H(\omega)=H^*(-\omega)\tag{3}$$

With $H(\omega)=|H(\omega)|e^{j\phi(\omega)}$ we get

$$|H(\omega)|=|H(-\omega)|\tag{4}$$

i.e., the magnitude of the frequency response is an even function of frequency, and

$$\phi(\omega)=-\phi(-\omega)\tag{5}$$

i.e., the phase is an odd function of frequency.

The same is true for discrete-time systems.

Comment: Yes, this was amongst one of conclusions I had but I wasn't sure. Thanks a lot for the confirmation! It's always a pleasure to read your answers :-)